# Why my solution is not true?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation, conditional-expectation

We know that $X_1,X_2$ and $X_3$ are three independent exponential random variables, with rates $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$, $\lambda_3$ respectively. We want to calculate $$E[\max{X_i}| X_1<X_2<X_3]$$
 The answer is equal to $$\frac{1}{\lambda_3}+\frac{1}{\lambda_2+\lambda_3}+\frac{1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3}$$
I have read the solution for this problem, and it seems to be correct for me, but I cannot understand why we cannot explain the following solution for this problem:

As we know that $X_1<X_2<X_3$, so $\max{X_i}=X_3$, hence we have $E[\max{X_i}| X_1<X_2<X_3]=E[X_3]=\frac{1}{\lambda_3}$

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your logic rigorously, one gets the correct identity $$E[\max{X_i}\mid X_1<X_2<X_3]=E[X_3\mid X_1<X_2<X_3].$$ Note that the RHS is *definitely not* $E[X_3]$.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively speaking, the solution you suggest simply *ignores* the constraint $X_1<X_2<X_3$. Yes, you calculate the expected value of $X_3$, but you include in your calculation events where $X_3$ is not the maximum.

Comment: I cannot understand the last part of your answer "but you include in your calculation events where $X_3$ is not the maximum". Can you explain more about your answer?